# Trying to make a prcedural fantasy encounter

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to write a random fantasy encounter.  Where randomly picking from the main list, will take you to a second list, which will take you to a third list:

- RUINS-> ruins-> manor->hut

or

- RUINS -> ruins-> village-> 4-24 hovels:

broad_categories = ['RUINS', 'RELICS', etc]

```
ruins = ['manor', 'village', 'city', etc]

manor = ['hut', 'hovel', 'hall', etc]
village = ['2-12 huts', '4-24 hovels', '6-36 cottages', etc]
city = ['7-42 huts and a citadel', '8-48 houses', etc]
```

so I wrote this:

```
a = random.randint(0, 1)
b = random.randint(0, 5)
c = random.randint(0, 5)

    def place():
        if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
            result = 'the ruins of hut'
        elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 1:
            result = 'the ruins of a hovel'
        elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 2:
            result = 'the ruins of a hall'
        elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 3:
            result = 'the ruins of a villa'
        elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 4:
            result = 'the ruins of a cottage'
        elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 5:
            result = 'the ruins of a palace'
```

etc...

It works, I just have a million elif statements and I'm iterating through every single list by hand.  Is there a better way to auto-generate a result?  So that when 'RUINS' is randomly picked it then goes to the 'ruins' list and then randomly picks 'manor village or city' and then based on that choice picks from those sub-lists lists?

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionaries for this. Here is an example.

```
import random

places = {
    "ruins": {
        "manor": ["hut", "hovel", "hall"],
        "vilage": ["2-12 huts", "4-24 hovels", "6-36 cottages"],
        "city": ["7-42 huts and a  citadel", "8-48 houses"],
    },
    # Add other places.
}

place = random.choice(list(places.values()))
# {'manor': ['hut', 'hovel', 'hall'],
#  'vilage': ['2-12 huts', '4-24 hovels', '6-36 cottages'],
#  'city': ['7-42 huts and a  citadel', '8-48 houses']}

place = random.choice(list(place.values()))
# ['2-12 huts', '4-24 hovels', '6-36 cottages']

place = random.choice(place)
# '8-48 houses'
```

A function to get a message with a random place might look like this:

```
def place():
    place = random.choice(list(places.values()))
    place = random.choice(list(place.values()))
    place = random.choice(place)
    return "the ruins of {}".format(place)
```

Also keep in mind that if you want `place` to get a random place on each call, you need to use a random value *inside* the function. In your code example, you get random values outside of the function, so the `place()` function will give you the same message on each call.